# How can I use reflection to retrieve all the fields and/or properties for a specific Type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to use reflection to retrieve the values of a field or property, for a particular type.

I do not know if

- it's a field
- it's a property
- either of the above are private or public.

I can't make assumptions so I was hoping to use reflection to solve this. I'm *hoping* that the developers will make these private fields ... but I cannot assume that.

How can I find all the fields/properties for a type `Foo` that has .. say.. `int`'s ?

.NET v 4.0 or 4.5 please. Linq is also acceptable :)

I want something like this pseudo-code:

```
var property = source.GetType()
                     .GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (int))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Now that you have edited in some code, what is the problem with that code?

Comment: "sorta like this"? What else do you want?

Comment: If you use `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` you will get both public and nonpublic instance properties. You also need to call `GetFields` with the same. You can also call `GetMembers` but it is slightly harder to use if you need to filter on property types and field types.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - can't do this? `BindingFlags.GetField |                                                          BindingFlags.GetProperty |                                                           BindingFlags.NonPublic |                                                           BindingFlags.Public` ?

Comment: You can't ask GetProperties to return fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that

```
const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
PropertyInfo[] properties = yourType.GetProperties(flags);
FieldInfo[] fields = yourType.GetFields(flags);

var intProperties = properties.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (int));
var intFields = fields.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof (int));
```

You can also write it like this (which is closer to your example)

```
const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

var intProperties = yourType.GetProperties(flags)
                    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (int));

var intFields = yourType.GetFields(flags)
                .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof (int));
```

Comment: But -- how does that filter out only one type .. say `int` or `Foo` or whatever?

Comment: like you mentioned yourType.GetProperties(flags).Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (int)); and yourType.GetFields(flags).Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof (int));

Comment: ``fields.Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(int))``